# Communication between C++ code and Python code

Tags: python, c++

I have to establish a communication between a **C++ code** and a **Python code** and sending messages in both directions ( first message will be from C++ to Python and then and until the rest of the program from Python to C++).

So my idea was to work with **UDP protocol** and to send a message from C++ code to Python code to tell him that he is ready to get messages until the end of the program and then to create a thread containing an infinit loop where the C++ is always listenning and trying to receive a message from Python.

The problem is when I execute the C++ code and the Python code, an error occur in the Python code says "Address already in use" and I think that it means that the port on which is the C++ thread is listenning is always busy.

My questions are:

1. What is the suitable communication protocol which support bidirectional communication ( code 1 is always listenning and code 2 is always listenning too and whoever who send message the second one must receive it)
2. If UDP is the suitable protocol, should I use two sockets and two ports or what?

Comment: Same machine? Named pipes is worth a try

Comment: There are *many* ways to do [*inter-process communication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Some which can only be done locally, and other which are better for remotely connected systems.

Comment: @arynaq yes same machine, it's beaglebone black rev c board

Comment: can anyone give an example where C++ and python are always listenning to each other and whoever send the other must receive please ?

Comment: `mosquitto` is nice and easy to get started with. You need to think about message sizes, data rates, message boundaries and whether messages should be stored if either side happens to be offline when the other sends. Is logging required too?

Comment: @MarkSetchell do u have a simple code example please ?

Comment: There are lots... http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto_pub-sub-clients/ or this https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/19/mqtt-protocol-ethernet/